# Not getting the text entered in EditText back to the calling activity with on Activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

MainActivity.java - Just having a button and a textview. Button click starts ExplicitlyLoadedActivity having an edittext. User type something and clicks "Enter" button, returns back to MainActivity.java with the text set on the textview of MainActivity.

```
public class ActivityLoaderActivity extends Activity {

static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public String text = "No Text Entered!";
String requiredValue="a";
// TextView that displays user-entered text from ExplicitlyLoadedActivity runs
private TextView mUserTextView;
Intent in;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader_activity);
    // Get reference to the textView
    mUserTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    // Declare and setup Explicit Activation button
Button explicitActivationButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.explicit_activation_button);
    explicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call startExplicitActivation() when pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startExplicitActivation();

        }
    });        
}


// Start the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity

private void startExplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered startExplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a new intent to launch the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent();
    explicitIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);


    // TODO - Start an Activity using that intent and the request code defined above
    startActivityForResult(explicitIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);


}    
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {

            requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("text").toString();
            mUserTextView.setText(requiredValue);
        } 
}
}
```

ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.java

```
public class ExplicitlyLoadedActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mEditText;
public String s = "abc";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.explicitly_loaded_activity);

    // Get a reference to the EditText field
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);



    // Declare and setup "Enter" button
    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call enterClicked() when pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enterClicked();         
        }
    });

}

// Sets result to send back to calling Activity and finishes

private void enterClicked() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");
    Toast.makeText(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, "Button clicked...",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
    s = mEditText.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, "Explicit : " + s,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as extra
    Intent i = getIntent(); //I don't know if this is the problem
    i.putExtra("text", s);
    // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

    // TODO - Finish the Activity
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build new Intent, replace "Intent i = getIntent()"  with - "Intent i= new Intent()"

Comment: Not helping. Text still not getting changed on mUserTextView in ActivityLoaderActivity.java.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected this issue is with your ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class. In the enterClicked() method you have created your Intent incorrectly. You need to put;

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
```

You should find your code works once this is done.

Regards,
V